# Results duplicating

Tags: oracle

My code below is duplicating my department name results and I don't know why. I need to display the name of the department, job id for the employees who work there and their salary. Plus I need to figure out if department_id or job_id was used in the CUBE expression.

```
SELECT d.department_name AS "Name", 
       e.job_id AS "Job ID", 
       SUM(e.salary) AS "salary", 
       DECODE(GROUPING(d.department_id),1, 'Yes', 'No') AS "Department Used", 
       DECODE(GROUPING(e.job_id), 1, 'Yes', 'No') AS "Job used"
FROM employees e 
    full OUTER JOIN departments d 
    ON (e.department_id = d.department_id)
GROUP BY CUBE(d.department_name, e.job_id, d.department_id)
ORDER BY d.department_name;
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

because cube generates subtotals for all combinations. in your example, combination works like that:

1) department_name - job_id - department_id

2) department_name - job_id

3) department_name - department_id

4) department_name

5) job_id - department_id

6) job_id

7) department_id

8) (total)

that's why you getting duplicate values.

I don't know what you exactly need, but I think you need something like that:

```
  select d.department_name as "Name",
         e.job_id as "Job ID",
         sum(e.salary) as "Salary",
         decode(grouping(d.department_id), 1, 'Yes', 'No') as "Department Used",
         decode(grouping(e.job_id), 1, 'Yes', 'No') as "Job Used"
    from hr.employees e
    full outer join hr.departments d
      on (e.department_id = d.department_id)
   group by cube(e.job_id), d.department_name, d.department_id
   order by d.department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `CUBE()` clause: you include two attributes from DEPARTMENT, so the results are cubed for all combinations of DEPARTMENT_ID and DEPARTMENT_NAME.

However, these two columns are correlated: there's a one to one relationship between ID and NAME (assuming you're using the HR schema or some other decent data model).

So the solution is quite simple: change the `CUBE()` clause to use one. As DEPARTMENT_NAME is in the projection that's the one to pick. You'll need to change the `DECODE()` to match.

```
SELECT d.department_name AS "Name", 
       e.job_id AS "Job ID", 
       SUM(e.salary) AS "salary", 
       DECODE(GROUPING(d.department_name),1, 'Yes', 'No') AS "Department Used", 
       DECODE(GROUPING(e.job_id), 1, 'Yes', 'No') AS "Job used"
FROM employees e 
    full OUTER JOIN departments d 
    ON (e.department_id = d.department_id)
GROUP BY CUBE(d.department_name, e.job_id)
ORDER BY d.department_name;
```